# Multiple light switches on single recessed light

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

Amateur basement remodeler here and learning as I make progress, but I had a question for all of the electrical professionals out there to see if someone can give me some pointers.

So before I begin explaining things, here is a picture for reference:

[image]

**Red**: The light switch it on top of the stairs upstairs and controls that one single light bulb.

**Yellow**: This used to be a standard light switch with a similar light bulb to the left but I switched it out for a dimmer and a recessed light which I'm linking in other places in the basement.

---

**Question**:

The Blue line is what I was wonder, would it be possible to link a recessed light that will be to the right with the left recessed light so all of my lights are run by the dimmer or would it not be possible since the light is already connected to a switch upstairs that controls that single basement light.

- Do I not use the upstairs switch and connect the lights?
- Could I use a standard switch upstairs that came with the house and just keep the recessed light run by that switch (No dimming possible).
- Or do I follow the left recessed light and hook it up to the right one and let both the dimmer and the switch run that single light.

All help would be appreciated!

Comment: What illuminates the stairway/stairwell?

Comment: There is a light in the stairway and it's a single switch outlet with 2 triggers, one trigger for the light in the stairway and one for that single basement light.

Comment: How open are you to running new/more cables up to the switch box for the stairwell basement lights?